Error in calculating FTIR and RAMAM using Quantum Espresso
I ran the following FTIR and RAMAN codes using Quantum Espresso. However, the calculations have not finished, can anyone tell me if my input files have any errors?
ph.in
&INPUTPH
      tr2_ph = 1.0d-12,
      asr=.true.,
      prefix = 'Si2CaP3O14',
      amass(1) = 28.08550,
      amass(2) = 40.07800,
      amass(3) = 30.97376,
      amass(4) = 15.99940,
      alpha_mix(1)=0.1,
      outdir = './tmp',
      fildyn = 'Si2CaP3O14.dyn',
/

dynmat .in
&INPUT
      fildyn = 'Si2CaP3O14.dyn',
      q(1) = 1.0,        !to correct for LO-TO splitting
      q(2) = 0.0,
      q(3) = 0.0,
      amass(1) = 28.08550,
      amass(2) = 40.07800,
      amass(3) = 30.97376,
      amass(4) = 15.99940,
      asr = 'simple',
      filout = 'dynmat.out',
/


Why did you set alpha_mix = 0.1 ? I think this means your input density at each step is almost identical to the previous, I.e. the density barely changes between SCF steps. I would expect convergence to be very slow.

I used as a basis another work I had done and it worked, that's why I chose this value. Do you have any suggestions for a value that would give me an ideal result?

It looks like this question is answered below: please consider accepting the answer so this question is marked solved. Thanks!

My comments got too long so I wrote an answer.
I suspect the issue is alpha_mix(1)=0.1.
For a generic SCF cycle (e.g. ground-state, DFPT, ...), input density/potential for the $i^{th}$ SCF step, $n^{i}_{in}$, is calculated from the input and output from the previous step, $n^{i-1}_{in}$ and $n^{i-1}_{out}$ respectively, according to $n^{i}_{in} = \alpha n^{i-1}_{out} +  (1 - \alpha ) n^{i-1}_{in}$.
If $\alpha=0.1$, which is your case, then at each step $n^{i}_{in} = 0.1 n^{i-1}_{out} + 0.9 n^{i-1}_{in}$ and the input density for the next SCF step is almost identical to the input for the previous step. If your initial guess for the density is very good, this is fine. That is rarely the case though, and it will require very many SCF steps to converge with $\alpha =0.1$.
The documentation for alpha_mix isn't great, so I went and looked at the source code to make sense of what is happening. In the ph.x program in Quantum ESPRESSO, $\alpha$ is controlled by alpha_mix(:), which can be set separately for every SCF step. By default, alpha_mix(1)=0.7 and all others are set to 0.0. At each SCF step, it checks if alpha_mix(i)=0; if so, it sets alpha_mix(i)=alpha_mix(i-1), i.e. it uses the $\alpha$ from the previous SCF step. So setting alpha_mix(1)=0.1 in the input file means $\alpha=0.1$ for all SCF steps, which is probably not ideal.
Quantum ESPRESSO uses $\alpha=0.7$ by default. It is rarely necessary to change this number unless you have convergence issues. In that case, I suggest testing different values of alpha_mix(1) in your input file and seeing which tends to converge most quickly.
Please try changing alpha_mix(1) in your input file or simply removing it to use the default and let me know if that helps! Considering accepting my answer if so.
Cheers!
Ty

I removed 'alpha_mix(1)=0.1' and ran it again, but my output file dynmat.out didn't run until the end, it only goes up to freq (60) = 58.804287 [THz] = 1961.499882 [cm^-1].

The ph.x file ran until the end

Great! You should accept the answer since we found a solution!

I think the dynmat.x problem is unrelated. Maybe see here https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/9106/1258 or post a new question! Cheers. Ty
